# Dynamic ng-model data as List/Array

Tags: angularjs

I created a form with an `input` text box with dynamically generated `ng-model` as below:

```
 <div class="row">
         <div class="column">Tags:</div>
         <div class="column">
            <select data-ng-options="tag.id as tag.name for tag in Tags"
             data-ng-model="formData.Tag">
                            </select>
        </div>
 </div>
   <div data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="column">Result {{$index + 1}}:</div>
             <div class="column">
              <input type="text" data-ng-model="formData.Result[$index + 1]"
               placeholder="Result {{$index + 1}}"><span>
              <button data-ng-show="$last" data-ng-click="addAnother()">Add
                  another</button>
              </span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On submitting the `form`, I am getting the data of field `Result` as a `JSON` below:

```
{"Tag":"1","Result":{"1":"1", "2":"2"}}
```

which I want to collect as a `list/array` like :   `{"Tag":"1","Result":["1", "2"]}`.

**.js**

```
myapp.controller(‘FormController', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.choices = [ {
    id : 'choice1'
} ];
$scope.addAnother = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
    $scope.choices.push({
        'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo
    });
  };
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : ‘/Application/submit',
            dataType : 'json',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            data : $scope.formData,
        });
        };
});
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: show us your controller

Comment: @simoco: added the controller code.

Comment: how `addAnother` method look like?

Comment: @simoco: updated the same too :)

Comment: Try to initialize your `formData` like this: `$scope.formData = {Tag:"", Result: [] };`

Comment: and also use  `data-ng-model="formData.Result[$index]"` instead of `data-ng-model="formData.Result[$index+1]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your controller initialize `formData`:

```
$scope.formData = {
    Tag:"",
    Result: []
  };
```

and in view use `data-ng-model="formData.Result[$index]"` instead of `data-ng-model="formData.Result[$index+1]"`. 
Here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkwF2rNstsxICrFiBh1q?p=info)